# put a text side of a primeng rating component

Tags: css, angular, html, primeng

Here is the [StackBlitz of my problem](https://stackblitz.com/github/primefaces/primeng-issue-template?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

```
<h6>
  <p-rating [(ngModel)]="raitng" [cancel]="false" ></p-rating>
<span> (5)</span>
</h6>
```

I want the last `<span>5</span>` just in the right or left side of the Rating component. How do I do this. Please see the [StakBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/github/primefaces/primeng-issue-template?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put your ngModel with string interpolation to between span tags
Like:

```
<h6>
  <p-rating [(ngModel)]="raitng" [cancel]="false" ></p-rating>
<span> {{raitng}}</span>
</h6>
```

**Updated** On right side just add style="display: inline-block;"  to p-rating element like:

```
<h6>
  <p-rating [(ngModel)]="raitng" style="display: inline-block;" [cancel]="false" ></p-rating>
<span> {{raitng}}</span>
</h6>
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. Though I worked it in another way.